# Cmake command line too long windows

Tags: windows, cmake

From my understanding of cmake, the tool takes care of file path and command lines length to avoid reaching windows limitation of 8191 characters.

However I'm cross compiling with arm_none_eabi on windows and cmake doesn't generate a makefile using response files or any other workaround for the path length. Thus the link step fails.

Here is the generated makefile line that causes issue

```
XXXXX_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS =
XXXX_OBJECTS = \
"file1.c.obj" \
"file2.c.obj" \
"file3.c.obj" \
"fileXX.c.obj" \

C:/YYYY/GNU_Tools_ARM_Embedded/6-2016-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe  -mcpu=cortex-m4  -mthumb -DSTM32L4__xx -mfloat-abi=softfp -DXXXX -O0 -g -Wfatal-errors -Wall -Wno-unused-function -std=c99 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections  -mcpu=cortex-m4  -march=armv7e-m -O0 -g --specs=nano.specs -mthumb -Wl,--gc-sections -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map=$@.map -TC:SSSSSSSSS/STM32L4__RGTx_FLASH.ld $(XXXX_OBJECTS) $(XXXXX_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS)  -o outHexFile_XXXX  -LC:/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY/arm-nano-eabi/lib
```

The final line length is about 23000 characters (far over 8191).

Why is Cmake not generating a makefile usable by windows ?
Is this only because I am cross-compiling ?
What can I do to avoid this issue ?

**EDIT**

Generator is GNU Makefiles

CMake Version 3.7.2

**EDIT 2**

this may be automatically handled in future versions

[submited bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16771)

Comment: I had the same problem and I have a solution which depends on the makefile generator e.g. Ninja you are using and the CMake version. Could you please add this information to your question?

Comment: @florian OK GNU makefile with Cmake 3.7.2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

I had the same problem with the command line length and could solve it with adding the following "use response file" settings to my toolchain file:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_OBJECTS 1)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_OBJECTS 1)

SET(CMAKE_C_RESPONSE_FILE_LINK_FLAG "@")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_RESPONSE_FILE_LINK_FLAG "@")
```

And if you would have had used `ninja` you would need an additional:

```
SET(CMAKE_NINJA_FORCE_RESPONSE_FILE 1 CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

Comment: This works, but for me this is still a cmake but. The tool should detect the limitation by itself.  I think the bug exists only in this special cross-compilation case

Comment: What do you mean by "your toolchain file"? Do I put this in every CMakeLists.txt, or?..

Comment: Is there some official documentation on these type of flags available?

Comment: can this be set for a particular target?

Comment: That's awesome. Works for me with CMake and Ninja on Windows. Thank you so much!