# cmake ninja command line too long

Tags: cmake, ninja

I am getting a `The command line is too long.` error when building on Windows using CMake 3.20.0 and Ninja 1.10.2.
I have tried the answer for [cmake-command-line-too-long-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184251/cmake-command-line-too-long-windows), but it did not work.
The actual command that is failing is the archiver:

```
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f path\to\mylib.a && C:\ti\ccs1010\ccs\tools\compiler\ti-cgt-arm_20.2.1.LTS\bin\armar.exe qr path\to\mylib.a <a-bunch-of-obj-files> && cd ."
```

I'm wondering if this is a bug (or lacking feature) of CMake where it needs to support using response files for archiving?
Is there a workaround or solution for this?